# I want to know the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a square is

Tags: real-analysis

I also have to show why the outer epsilon border square is rounded at the corners, but not the inner epsilon square.If that makes sense. I would think I have to look at each line of the square and not the whole square itself. Any ideas on how to start?

Comment: Imagine that you have a ball of radius $\epsilon$ that "walk" along the border of the square. Can you see what happens?

Comment: Maybe start to see what happens for a line segment, fix a radius and let a circle centered on a point $p$ on the line segment. Now move $p$ along the line segment, what can of region does that described? Then do the same for the square and you should see that the corners are rounded outside the square and stays corners in the square.

Comment: Considering $\epsilon$ neighbourhood at the corners, it does not in fact touch in the inner epsilon border. Not until you are $\epsilon$ away from the corner does that happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

[image]

The corner circle gives the outer rounded corner, but does not reach the inner square corner.

Comment: Did you whip this up yourself? If so, it's pretty good!

Comment: @CameronWilliams: a combination of GeoGebra and MSPaint

Comment: Wow that does help. It was hard ti imagine, but don't know how to start off proving what I see in that picture.